# meaning of "intervening area"

Tags: meaning

I am learning an [ELU post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/250710/376348), which says

> The inclusion of 'over' as a pre-modifier to the locatives / directionals 'here' or 'there' connotes the **intervening area**.

Cambridge Dictionary gives this definition about "intervening"

> happening between two times or between other events or activities

Based on which, I guess "intervening area" means an area between other areas. So, is it the correct way to describe the area pointed out by red rectangle shown below as "intervening area"?

[image]

If yes, it is an "intervening area" between which areas? the other 8 blocks? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area doesn't mean "city block"

If you are on Independence Ave and I am on C St SW, then the area around a line drawn between us (in some very vague an not specially defined way) is the intervening area.

There is an area between the National Museum of Native American History and the Mary E Switzer Building.  That "intervening area" would include the Voice of America building, and sections of several streets and avenues, and a grassy area in front of the Museum.  But an "area" doesn't mean "city block".

Nobody every talks like that, except when trying to be very precise (for example to explain a detailed point of English Usage, like the meaning of "over" in "over here".)